# Cypher: Concatenation and matching of strings obtained with UNWIND

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

In a cypher query, I end up with a collection of strings. Then, for each of these strings, I would like to check whether they are a substring of a property of a set of nodes. I am trying to do the substring matching using regular expressions, like in the example:

```
MATCH (x:Company)
WITH collect(DISTINCT x.name) AS all_company_names
UNWIND all_company_names AS company_name
MATCH (s:Division)
WHERE s.name =~ company_name + '.*'
RETURN s
```

However, the string concatenation gives me the following error:

```
Type mismatch: expected Collection<Boolean> but was String (line 5, column 32)
```

I wonder what does UNWIND return? Why what it returns can not be concatenated with a string? Or is there something else which is wrong with my query?

Thanks!

Comment: See [UNWIND](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-unwind.html)

Comment: I have checked it already, and according to the Cypher [refcard](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard/), I don't see any problem to treat each row returned by UNWIND as a string. Yet, I don't understand why the concatenation gives me an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chance, I spotted a line in an answer of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792040/query-for-name-not-like-other-name-in-neo4j-cypher), saying:

> Since the operator order between string concatenation and regexp comparison is not obvious, it's probably best to put the string concatenation in parenthesis too

Putting the full concatenation of the string with a regular expression in parenthesis solved my problem:

```
WHERE s.name =~ (company_name + '.*')
```